# Adding UITapGestureRecognizer to the UIControl

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, uicontrol

I've got a slider class (`class Slider: UIControl`) which has been created programmatically and I want to add a double tap gesture to resize it to the default settings. Unfortunatelly I can't implement the UITapGestureRecognizer like I did before in SpriteKit.

part of the code:

```
class Slider: UIControl{
   ...
   let doubleTap : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped))
   ...

   init(){
      ...
      doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
      addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
   }

   func doubleTapped(){
      print("double tapped")
   }
}
```

For now I would like to implement just the gesture recognizer and then add what I need to do. Also I've implemented touchesMoved and touchesBegan.

Comment: First of all, initialization selector in let won't work, object is not fully initialized at this time, move it to init. Then try to use delegate to determine the reasons of not-called selector, may be some of system gesture recognizers take events from yours.

Comment: Why are the `init` and `doubleTapped` methods outside of the class instead of part of the class?

Comment: @rmaddy that was a mistake, init and doubleTapped is inside the class

Comment: Then please edit your question showing proper code.

Comment: @vojer how to use a delegate here? `doubleTap.delegate = self` returns the error: Cannot assign value of type 'Slider' to type 'UIGestureRecognizerDelegate'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the answer is very simple, no delegate needed.

```
class Slider: UIControl{
   ...

   init(){
      ...
      let doubleTap : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped))
      doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
      addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
   }

   func doubleTapped(){
      print("double tapped")
   }
}
```